# Delete instance of class within that class

Tags: c#-4.0

How can I delete an object's instance within its own class?  If I had a class named *Bullet* for example, and it collided with an instance of class *Box*, then it would be logical and simple to delete the bullet instance after it collides.  I could do this usually by setting it to null, but I cannot set an instance of a class to null within its own class because if I try

```
this = null;
```

It won't work since *this* is read-only.  My question is two-fold:

1) Is there a simple way to do this?
2) If there isn't, then what would be a strong alternative?

Comment: Delete *from where*? If there is no reference from anywhere elsen (i.e. outside of your instance) to your instance, you can consider your instance deleted automatically (the garbage collector will remove it sooner or later). The same can be said about a whole graph of interconnected objects, by the way.

Comment: Oh, you're right! I was planning on putting it into a bulletIndex which would store the list of all currently active bullets on the screen and update them and such. At that point, I could just remove it from bulletIndex (a List object) and subtract 20 from the player's health.  I was thinking too narrowly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is: you obviously can't because the instance is not a reference to itself--you need to delete the outside reference.

Long answer:
You need to to delete it somewhere else.  That can be where you're invoking the detection (i.e. the call into Bullet). For example:

```
if(bullet.DetectCollision())
{
    bullet=null;
}
```

Or, have another class that manages the instances and remove the instances from some sort of collection.

If your classes may implement IDisposable, you'll likely want to also deal with invoking Dispose() as well.

But, it's really hard to know what you really need with the description you've provided.

Comment: My description is vague because I thought it was complete.  If I had known what I was missing from the description, this question wouldn't have existed because I would've put two and two together.  Thanks for trying to figure out what I meant.